# cleartext communication to localhost not permitted by network security policy react native

Tags: react-native

[image]

I am trying to debug my react native code but everytime I try to connect remote debugger i get following error.

cleartext communication to localhost not permitted by network security policy react native

Is any wayout or reason for this. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in the manifest in the application label:

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"